# Remove Bottom Whitespace from UILabel

Tags: swift, uiview, uilabel

I'm trying to get my `UILabel` text to be right along the bottom of the view, however I haven't been able to get rid of it.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
@IBOutlet weak var securityCodeLabel: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        // This also didn't work
        //securityCodeLabel.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(securityCodeLabel.layoutMargins.top, securityCodeLabel.layoutMargins.left, 0, securityCodeLabel.layoutMargins.right)

        securityCodeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(securityCodeLabel.frame.origin.x, securityCodeLabel.frame.origin.y, securityCodeLabel.frame.size.width, (securityCodeLabel.frame.size.height - securityCodeLabel.font.descender))
    }
}
```

The effect I'm after:

[image: UILabel]

As you can see the text is right along the bottom of the view.

Comment: Try the Format Inspector in the interface builder. I'm pretty sure there's an option to make the text align to the bottom of the label instead of the middle

Comment: Label Baseline issue?

Comment: @Arc676 the view mode is set to left, setting it to bottom doesn't change anything... there is also an align baselines options but this is just how the letters line up if the label is resizing.. if it's not either of those i'm not sure what you're talking about?

Comment: How would letter 'y' (small caps 'Y') look in this case?

Comment: @Eimantas https://gyazo.com/33df9282e3345f81685048b456631f9f. I know the descender would be outside the UIView if i removed it but I know all my letters are going to be capitals and so I don't want the space there.